# how to link fftw3 to eclipse mars c++?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to link fftw3 library to eclipse with no success so far. I included the header file fftw3.h in 'paths and symbol' and it able to recognize fft_complex and fft_plan but these are unreferenced

undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_destroy_plan'
undefined reference to`__imp_fftw_execute'
undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_malloc'
undefined reference to`__imp_fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d'

Please help. Im new to eclipse

Answer (score 1):

These functions (`__imp_fftw_destroy_plan`) are not defined in the header: the path to the fftw library must be provided. If you wish to keep on using the building utilies of eclispe, here are the following steps to complete:

1) Right click on the project name and click on `Properties`.

2) in C/C++ General/Path and Symbols, click on the `Include` flap. You have added the path to `fftw3.h` for C++. This corresponds to the include search path of g++, the `-I` flag.

3) click on the `Library Paths` flap and add the path to `libfftw3.a`. This corresponds to the library search path `-L` of g++.

4) click on the `Libraries` flap and add `fftw3`. That way, `-lfftw3` is added to the linking step of the build procedure and `g++` will look for `libfftw3.a`.

As the project is built, the following commands appears in the Console window:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/fftwineclipse.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/.../fftw_bidon/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/fftwineclipse.d" -MT"src/fftwineclipse.d" -o "src/fftwineclipse.o" "../src/fftwineclipse.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/fftwineclipse.cpp

Building target: fftwineclipse
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/.../fftw_bidon/lib -o "fftwineclipse"  ./src/fftwineclipse.o   -lfftw3
Finished building target: fftwineclipse
```

You can look at these lines which reflect the settings you have provided in steps 2-4

Of course, the fftw3 library must have been completely installed on your computer first. See packages `libfftw3-3` and `libfftw3-dev` (static library `libfftw3.a`) in your package manager (unix). If you use MinGW on windows, [MinGW supports libraries named according to the "libfftw3.lib" and "libfftw3.dll" conventions, in addition to the normal "libfftw3.a" convention common on *nix systems.](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use) See [here](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html) to get precompiled FFTW 3.3.4 windows DLLs. Whatch out: it's `libfft3-3.dll`.

You can also call your own building procedure by unticking the `Use default buid command` in `C/C++ Builder` flap of the properties of the project. That way, you can provide you own command. You can also write your own makefile by unticking `generate Makefiles automatically` and by modifying the build location.

Here is a minimum piece of code to create a project and test if fftw is properly linked:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fftw3.h>

using namespace std;



int main() {

    int N=42;
    fftw_complex in[N], out[N];
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N,in,out,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    cout << "end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i add library directory and libfftw3-3 into library tab. theres no previous error show but i have build error which doesnt show in console for ome reason. in my fftw folder there are libfftw3-3.dll , libfftw3l-3.dll. In the library tab, i included libfftw3-3 without extension dll .

Comment: im using mingw c++ also

Comment: when i add libfftw3-3. theres a comment below saying 'ambiguous relative path'. the program run but terminated with value different than 0 which is indicating error but no error shown

Comment: @minhnguyen : I added a minimal piece of code to my answer so that you can test whether fftw is properly linked or not. If it works with this piece of code, the problem may be elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I would use cmake to create the project.
Here is the fftw part I use (with VC but should work with Eclipse too).

PS: And yes I am a little lazy to create a project where I do not need to manually change the path while debuging

```
set (FFTW_DIR "C://fftw-3.3.4-dll32")
...
find_path (FFTW_DIR fftw3.h)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FFTW_DIR})
link_directories("${FFTW_DIR}")
...

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(libfftw3-3 libfftw3f-3 libfftw3l-3)
```

Comment: can you please provide some details ? i dont know cmake. and im using windows

Comment: Cmake is a software to create (plattform independent) solution files for different types of build systems (visual studio, make, codeblocks, xcode,...).
You create cmakelist files in whichyou write where to find source, header, qt ui files, ... open it with cmake and create your solutions.
At the beginning it is a little confusing but after a while you will not want to miss it because you can write c++ code and create solution files for visual studio or linux make files without editing (hopefully).